# Why are C++ templates dynamically typed?

Tags: dynamic

Why are C++ templates dynamically typed?

Answer (score 6):

They aren't.

Dynamic typing would mean that types are not known until runtime. C++ templates know the types at compile time. They work like macros, producing many versions of the same code for different types.